# calling restfull webservice throwing error in URI

Tags: android, web-services, restful-url

I have written a logic that calls a android webservice passing few paramters. The problem is when i send query it returns an error message which i m getting as an xml. the url that i want to call is 
http://192.168.1.10:8080/ymaws/resources/restaurantcityid=33498&areanm=vasant vihar
but i m getting error.The code is below. Plz suggest a good way to do this

```
String list = null;
                restaurantnames=new ArrayList<String> ();   
                areanames=new ArrayList<String>();
                restaurantidlist=new ArrayList<String>();

                final HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    String url = "http://192.168.1.10:8080/ymaws/resources/restaurant?cityid="+cityid+"&areanm="+area.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String encodedurl = null;
                try
                {
                        encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
                } 
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) 
                {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("TEST", encodedurl);

                final HttpGet req=new HttpGet(encodedurl);
                HttpResponse httpResponse;
                try {
                        httpResponse=client.execute(req);
                        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        Log.i("entity", entity.toString());
                        if (entity != null) 
                        {
                            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                            String line = null;
                            try 
                            {
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                                {
                                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                                }
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                            finally 
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                    instream.close();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                            list= sb.toString();
                            Log.i("list xml is", list.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply adding "amp;" after the "&" sign. (couldn't write & + amp; together since SO made it to only "&" hehe) :)

Comment: I wrote it this way and it forced closed again. I think i m doing it wrong again.  <http://192.168.1.10:8080/ymaws/resources/restaurant?cityid="+cityid+"&amp;cuisineid="+cuisineidlist.get(i)+"&amp;areanm="+area.getSelectedItem().toString()>                                                                    The request should be formed as <http://192.168.1.10:8080/ymaws/resources/restaurant?cityid=33114&cuisineid=1&areaname=gurgaon> Any further suggestion?   Thanks for help dear BTW

Comment: Friends got the solution. Actually I couldnt understand the problem.The real problem was that i was passing the last parameter that contained spaces. Thats wht was throwing error. Now i need to work on how to remove those spaces. I knw %20 is the way but  need to implement some logic

Answer (score 0):

This might require u to use Apache's opensource libs, but it works for me in all my code:

```
public static String getHTTP(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = "";     
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();           

        // Execute HTTP Get Request
        result = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        return result;
}
```

The required libs are :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import java.io.IOException;
```

You can get the Apache Http Client jars [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Comment: its working as it is if we call to a url like "http://192.168.1.10:8080/ymaws/resources/restaurant/"+cityid+"/cuisines/" which returns xml of city wise cuisine. But i think it has something to do with that "?" sign that i m passing in url

Comment: Am not sure how u r doing the back-end, but if passing in url params is what's messing this up, how about u change the url scheme to something like: `/ymaws/resources/restaurant/city_id/area_nm/`? So u just pick off those as params to the handler. At least Django offers this pretty easily :-)

Comment: Friends got the solution. Actually I couldnt understand the problem.The real problem was that i was passing the last parameter that contained spaces. Thats wht was throwing error. Now i need to work on how to remove those spaces. I knw %20 is the way but  need to implement some logic